# Checking for duplicate values in database with Python

Tags: python, performance, database

I'm working on a Python application where I read and extract data from an HTML file. The data is stored in a list, and the number of items in a list is, on average, 50,000+. 
The items from the list are added to a database. I cannot allow duplicate datetime values in one of the columns, and so, I have to check if a specific value exists in the database already, and if it does, keep incrementing it until there's no duplicates.

Here's what my code looks like (I'm using SQLAlchemy):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from models import db, Notes

def import_file(filename, user):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    html = file.read()
    file.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        validurl = re.compile(
            r'^(?:[a-z0-9\.\-]*)://'
            r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}(?<!-)\.?)|'
            r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|'
            r'\[?[A-F0-9]*:[A-F0-9:]+\]?)'
            r'(?::\d+)?'
            r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
        url = validurl.match(link.get('href'))
        if url:
                url = link.get('href')
                if len(url) <= 2000:
                    if link.get('add_date'):
                        date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(link.get('add_date')))
                        while Notes.query.filter_by(user=user, added_on=date).first():
                            date += timedelta(0, 1)
                        title = link.string
                        import_notes = Notes()
                        import_notes.main_url = url
                        import_notes.title = title
                        import_notes.user = user
                        import_notes.added_on = date
                        db.session.add(import_notes)
                        db.session.commit()
```

However, this code runs very slowly. I calculated how long it was taking per insert, and it came out at exactly 13 seconds per insert. I ran a profiler, and the `filter_by query` was taking the majority of the time. I figured it was because the script had to run a query so many times per item, and so I changed my code to use a static list instead:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from models import db, Notes

def import_file(filename, user):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    html = file.read()
    file.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        validurl = re.compile(
            r'^(?:[a-z0-9\.\-]*)://'
            r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}(?<!-)\.?)|'
            r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|'
            r'\[?[A-F0-9]*:[A-F0-9:]+\]?)'
            r'(?::\d+)?'
            r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
        url = validurl.match(link.get('href'))
        if url:
                url = link.get('href')
                if len(url) <= 2000:
                    if link.get('add_date'):
                        date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(link.get('add_date')))
                        while Notes.query.filter_by(user=user, added_on=date).first():
                            date += timedelta(0, 1)
                        title = link.string
                        import_notes = Notes()
                        import_notes.main_url = url
                        import_notes.title = title
                        import_notes.user = user
                        import_notes.added_on = date
                        db.session.add(import_notes)
                        db.session.commit()
```

I thought this might make the code run faster, but there was little to no change in runtime. For comparison, if I remove the duplicate check, I get ~300 inserts per second.

I cannot let duplicate datetime values into the database. What can I do to make my code faster?

Comment: Why do you have that requirement about no multiple dates though?

Comment: I am using the dates for pagination. I can't use ids since I allow imports, and the dates on imported items can be older, but the id would then be higher. If I have too many duplicate dates on a page, then the forward/backward buttons stop working(ie, they redirect to the same page).

Comment: Maybe you should try using a set, checking if a value is inside a set is extremely fast.

Comment: I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @Caridorc your suggestion to use a set solved my problem. Down from 13 seconds per insert to 0.009. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, the real bottleneck was the incredible amount of database lookups: `while Notes.query.filter_by(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In python checking membership of an item in a set is extremely fast](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set).

I suggest you use sets.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Caridorc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/54718/caridorc)'s answer about using sets instead of lists,
a few more things beg for improvement.

#### Working with files

Use `with ... as ...` when working with files,
to make sure that you cannot forget closing them.
So instead of this:

> ```
> file = open(filename, 'r')
> html = file.read()
> file.close()
> ```

Write like this:

```
with open(filename) as fh:
    html = fh.read()
```

(I also omitted the mode parameter of `open`, as `'r'` is the default.

#### Move non-changing calculation out of a loop

In this loop, `validurl` is the same in every iteration:

> ```
> for link in soup.find_all('a'):
>     validurl = re.compile(
>         r'^(?:[a-z0-9\.\-]*)://'
>         r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}(?<!-)\.?)|'
>         r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|'
>         r'\[?[A-F0-9]*:[A-F0-9:]+\]?)'
>         r'(?::\d+)?'
>         r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
>     url = validurl.match(link.get('href'))
> ```

It should be done just once before the loop begings:

```
validurl = re.compile(
    r'^(?:[a-z0-9\.\-]*)://'
    r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}(?<!-)\.?)|'
    r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|'
    r'\[?[A-F0-9]*:[A-F0-9:]+\]?)'
    r'(?::\d+)?'
    r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    url = validurl.match(link.get('href'))
```

#### Indentation

Indentation in Python is very important,
and so it's important to do it consistently.
For example this looks suspicious:

> ```
> if url:
>         url = link.get('href')
>         if len(url) <= 2000:
>             if link.get('add_date'):
> ```

In most of the program you correctly indented with 4 spaces,
but after `if url` there you indented by 8 spaces.
This is confusing, and it should be corrected.

Comment: There's a typo: `html = file.read()` should really be `html = fh.read()`. Also, you could mention that `file` is a reserved word in python, a synonym of `open`. And that's why you changed the variable name to `fh`.

Comment: Thanks for that! I fixed the typo. As for the reserved word... Is it really? In Python 2.x it's a class. In Python 3 it doesn't look like a reserved word. I could object about Python 2, but the version used is not clear, and since using Python 3 is recommended anyway, I don't feel it's important enough to bring it up. If you think otherwise, I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Agreed, all points valid. The distinction between a function and a class (constructor) wasn't clear to me. I'd avoid using this name for clarity, anyway.